# Sony ericsson(Android) Phone not getting detected in eclipse?

Tags: android, android-emulator, sony

I have sony ericsson LT26i phone(India). I have turned on the Development mode.
Still I am not able to detect the phone in the eclipse. This phone is getting detected in normal mode to browse the files and all.

Other phones are detected in eclipse like samsung etc.

Comment: you ll have to install the drivers for debugging

Comment: Drivers are there so only phone is getting detcted.

Comment: not that one the driver for debuging http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't write what OS you run.

In Linux you do

```
> lsusb
```

and you get a list of the likes:

> Bus 001 Device 009: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd

you edit the rules file:

```
> sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/99-android.rules
```

adding
 SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTR{idProduct}=="6860", MODE="0666", OWNER="`<your login here>`"

need also do

```
> sudo service udev restart
> adb kill-server
> adb start-server
```

check with

```
> adb devices
```

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue with my Sony Xperia Neo L phone. As mentioned in the above post, you can work this out in linux platform with the answer of "opaque". But if you are a Windows 7 user (As i was), best and easiest way is to install the Sony PC Companion software from sony web site.

this software has installed the required drivers and after that my eclipse has detected my phone.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried opaque's solution as is, I wasn't able to get my Xperia Pro to be identified on Ubuntu 13.04. As for what I could understand from this post (http://esausilva.com/2010/05/13/setting-up-adbusb-drivers-for-android-devices-in-linux-ubuntu/), I wasn't creating the android-rules file right.

To solve this I checked for other rules files on the rules.d directory and found out that it should be 70-andoid.rules, in my case. After that it still didn't recognize the device, but, after changing the file's permissions and rebooting the system, as also said on the cited post, Ubuntu is now identifying it ok.

Hope it helps!